# C# Forms with negative minimum value in progress bar

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, winforms

I need to show a progress bar that have negative values, but when i try to modify the value to a negative number, the c# gets an error (invalid property error). Does anyone knows any method to create a negative value progress bar?

```
HPHeroi.Maximum = CriacaoDePersonagem.protagonista.status.Vida;
HPHeroi.Minimum = -20;
```

Answer (score 3):

> Does anyone knows any method to create a negative value progress bar?

You cannot. From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.progressbar.minimum):

> ### Exceptions
>
> [ArgumentException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentexception)
>
> The value specified for the property is less than 0.

Instead, what you need to do is offset the entire range of the progress bar to account for the negative value. E.g.:

```cs
HPHeroi.Maximum = CriacaoDePersonagem.protagonista.status.Vida + 20;
HPHeroi.Minimum = 0;
```

Then you need to also account for that when you set the current value of the `ProgressBar`, e.g.:

```cs
HPHeroi.Value = CriacaoDePersonagem.protagonista.status.ActualVida + 20;
```

The above strategy can be encapsulated in a `UserControl` that wraps a `ProgressBar`, exposing the various value-related properties but using an offset to ensure that the actual `ProgressBar` object doesn't see negative values.

For example:

```cs
public partial class ProgressBarWithNegativeValues : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _offset;

    public ProgressBarWithNegativeValues()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int Minimum
    {
        get => progressBar1.Minimum + _offset;
        set
        {
            int offsetChange = value - _offset;

            _offset = value;
            progressBar1.Maximum -= offsetChange;
            _RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Maximum
    {
        get => progressBar1.Maximum + _offset;
        set
        {
            progressBar1.Maximum = value - _offset;
            _RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get => progressBar1.Value + _offset;
        set
        {
            progressBar1.Value = value - _offset;
            _RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Step
    {
        get => progressBar1.Step;
        set
        {
            progressBar1.Step = value;
            _RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void Increment(int step) => progressBar1.Increment(step);

    public void PerformStep() => progressBar1.PerformStep();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void _RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I've omitted the `*.Designer.cs` code because that's just a single `ProgressBar` object dropped onto the `UserControl` with its `Dock` property set to `Fill`.

Note in the above that the `ProgressBar.Minimum` property is always left at 0, and the other properties offset accordingly, whether the minimum value is negative or positive. This keeps the code nice and simple instead of trying to deal with the negative and positive cases separately.

Comment: Doens't help cause allways i use a command that decreases the progress bar to below 0, the program crashes =/

Comment: Sorry...I don't understand what you mean by "doesn't help". You don't have a choice, _at all_. If you want to use the built-in `ProgressBar`, you **must** not attempt to use values for the progress bar that are negative. Period. The above is exactly what you **must** do if you have ranges would otherwise include negative numbers. If you want a progress bar that accepts negative numbers, you need to either switch to WPF, or you need to write your own progress bar implementation from scratch ...

Comment: ... (you could accomplish the latter as a `UserControl` that uses a `ProgressBar` internally, and does the mapping I show above).

Answer (score 1):

As Peter have stated, a progress bar can not hold a negative number. Therefore you can not use a Progress bar for this.

What I suggest, is instead of using a progress bar, use a track bar and disable it (set it's Enabled property to false).

Therefore, Imagine `HPHeroi` is a **TrackBar** object:

```
HPHeroi.Maximum = CriacaoDePersonagem.protagonista.status.Vida;
HPHeroi.Minimum = -20;
```

The code above will not result in a runtime error.

Keep in mind, there might be 2 more runtime errors that will occur when you reach the Maximum and Minimum values. To overcome them, add an if statement before each subtraction and addition of the HPHeroi's value (remember, it is a TrackBar now).

If statement example for subtraction:

```
if (HPHeroi.Value > HPHeroi.Minimum)
    HPHeroi.Value--;
```

If statement example for addition:

```
if (HPHeroi.Value < HPHeroi.Maximum)
    HPHeroi.Value++;
```

P.S. If you want, you can add a lable with "0" as content and put it under the line of the value of 0 in the track bar so that the user will know when the value is positive and when it is negative.

Answer (score 1):

ProgressBar has a minimum value of 0, but the maximum can be quite high.
If you need it to represent a negative value, just use an offset.

```
int Offset = 20;
HPHeroi.Maximum = CriacaoDePersonagem.protagonista.status.Vida + Offset;
HPHeroi.Minimum = 0;
```

When you set the value of HPHeroi, simply add Offset to the new value

```
HPHeroi.Value = newvalue + Offset
```

*newvalue* can therefore be anything from -20 to CriacaoDePersonagem.protagonista.status.Vida, the range you are trying to specify, and your ProgressBar will show that.